# How can I perform a partial matching of the command name using `ps -C`?

Tags: process, ps

I find the `ps -C <cmd>` option very useful, since it lets me limit the output of `ps` to only those processes started with command name `<cmd>`.

Compared to performing a `grep`, I also get the header with columns in the output.

However, it appears I can only do a full command name matching using `ps -C <cmd>`. In other words, if the command name is `/opt/azagent/bin/Agent.Listener run --startuptype service`, then only `ps -C Agent.Listener` will list it, and not any partial match, like `ps -C Agent`.

Is it possible to perform a partial match using `ps -C <cmd>` on Debian?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `pgrep`

> NAME
>
> pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    pgrep [options] pattern
>    pkill [options] pattern
> ```

Comment: I wouldn't say those commands serve the same purpose as `ps`.